# What happens if you blow the ashes as soon as a Phoenix dies?

Tags: harry-potter, phoenix

Phoenixes are immortal, they die and are reborn from their ashes. But what happens if we blow the ashes as soon as the Phoenix dies? And what happens if we recollect those ashes in a place?

Comment: It makes an awful mess in your room

Comment: Blowing a fire only enhances it. The image that comes to mind for me is the ashes are blown into the air, they glow bright and a more adult Phoenix is born in mid flight. Speculative of course.

Comment: What about using vacuum cleaner?

Comment: Ah, so THAT's the backstory to all the ashes on the table where Kilo Ren put his helmet when he decided to show his awesomely un-scary hair to Rey.

Comment: You get one mixed up Phoenix. Please note that the Phoenix rises from the ashes, it does not reconstitute from them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ‘Fawkes is a phoenix, Harry. Phoenixes burst into flame when it
>   is time for them to die and are reborn from the ashes. Watch him ...’
>   Harry looked down in time to see a tiny, wrinkled, new-born
>   bird poke its head out of the ashes. It was quite as ugly as the old
>   one.

Here we seem Fawkes emerges from a pile of ashes, but

> Fawkes swooped down in front of Dumbledore, opened his beak
>   wide and swallowed the jet of green light whole: he burst into
>   flame and fell to the floor, small, wrinkled and flightless.

Here we see Fawkes dies and is reborn immediately in mid air, while falling so his pile of ashe is most likely spread out.

Based on this quote it appears nothing would happen should you try to move or separate the ashes, and since the phoenix is reborn immediately you don't really have time to "stop" the rebirth by messing with the ashes anyway.

Side note, phoenix are not immortal,

> The phoenix lives to an
>   immense age as it can regenerate, bursting into flames when its
>   body begins to fail and rising again from the ashes as a chick.

Comment: hmm... instantaneous was the thing... thanks!! :D...

Comment: Phoenixes are supposed to be immortals which means not dying because of age, but is it possible that a phoenix would die for example by the Avada Kadabra?

Comment: @hedgehog my quote shows fwakes eating an aveda with no problem

Comment: @Himarm he actually "ate" it he didnt take the hit though, which puts me into thoughts...

Comment: @hedgehog: There's a difference? I'm pretty sure that being hit with a vat full of highly concentrated hydrochloric acid, or drinking said vat of hydrochloric acid will result in the same thing: a very bad day.

Comment: @Ellesedil well you could potentially live with major 3rd degree burns from 1, as opposed to your digestive track burning up :P

Comment: Phoenixes may be immortal. "Lives to an immense age" could mean "no one has seen a dead one and we assume they die at some time".